# ssh2 cannot login using either publickey or password. Totally locked out

Tags: ssh, passwords, public-key, solaris-10, libssh2

I am not able to login to our production server when I tried to login without password.   The server is solaris and using secure shell ssh2.   It doesnot accept the public key or the password.  Now I am totally locked out.

I get to password prompt but right after I type password it gives the following error.

ssh server
admin@sever's password:
Authenticated with partial success.
Permission denied (publickey).

This is a severe issue.  Please help.

Comment: Off-topic as this is not a programming related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's trying to use multi-factor authentication maybe. I don't know how to make libssh2 do that but it can be done easily enough with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html). An example follows:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'pass1', 'code1')) {
    exit('Login failed');
}
// this does the same thing as the above
//if (!$ssh->login($username, 'pass1') && !$ssh->login('username', 'code1')) {
//    exit('Login failed');
//}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

src: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html#multifactor

Comment: Thank you for your answer!.  But I do not know php and how to implement the above solution.  Can you please direct on how to do this?